# Pipe Slice throws error when navigating from another page

Tags: angular, typescript

When refreshing the page or defaulting to the page on loading the project, slicing the array works. 
The problem is when I navigate to the home.component and then return back to the slice.component I receive this:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./XXXXXXComponent - inline template:105:28 caused by: Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'SlicePipe'
>   Error: Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'SlicePipe'

```
<div class="card-block" *ngFor="let something of something.data | slice:0:5"></div>
```

Something.data is an array.

Comment: What does `something.data` contain?

Comment: An Array of objects.

Comment: The error indicates that it is an object instead of an array of objects

Comment: Console.log on the component ngOnInit shows me that it is an array of objects. The moment I navigate away and come back it is showing Object {attributes: Object}. It just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Not sure, there are few API calls and component dependencies. Thanks anyway, I am keep digging.